# H2o Sparkling water and Duke Library

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

We started a POC of Sparkling water and realized they are internally using the [duke library](https://github.com/larsga/Duke). Nor sure what features of Duke Library H2o.

Duke allows to use custom comparators? Does h2o exposes this feature ?

I have gone through the source code and the only reference i see is during the H2oContext Initialization they are making sure the Duke Library Comparator is loaded. How ever i didn't see any other places where they are actually using the comparators.

Thanks

Comment: SW (or H2O) does not expose custom comparators. You can use comparators that are built-in Duke in PySparkling and/or RSparkling. Documentation for PySparkling: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/frame.py#L2200

This feature is not directly exposed in the Scala API as of now.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Are there any plans of exposing this feature in scala API in the near future ? Could you pls let us know.

Comment: It can be added, please make a feature request in our JIRA: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/